# How to put two different type inputs in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, types, casting

I want to input two or more different types of numbers (float and integer) on the same line.

For example, I know I can do this:
`a, b = map(int, input().split())`

But this will give me two integers, I want it to be an integer and a float. 
Any ways of putting two or more different types of data in a split input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes one solution:

```
a, b, c = list( t(v) for (t, v) in zip( [type1, ..., typeN], input().split()) )
```

---

**Explanation**

The ideia is use [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) to relate `type function` and `input value` ordered.

To do this, we [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) a list of predefined `type functions` with its specific `input value`, throwing each pair to be mapped.

The result is a list with the values already typed, so you can unpack it to name each one in a variable